# Using Imageview in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

I am trying to set an imageview in a Fragment:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.qrCode);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get the error

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a
>   null object reference".

This works if I have it in a class that extends AppCompatActivity but not in my fragment class.

The corresponding xml file is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<!--   tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" > -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_logout"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qrCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the imageview belonging to fragment layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container,
            false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qrCode);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getActivity()` use `getView()`

Like this

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
```

inside your fragment

getActivity() returns the activity object to whome your fragment is attached whereas `getView()` will return you the rootview of your fragment inside of which all other views are present and you can then find them by their id's.

Answer (score 0):

Make it public static in your activity class and use it in your fragment as below:

In your activity;

```
 public static ImageView imageView;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT);


 imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.qrCode);

}
```

In your fragment,

```
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
    YOURACITVITYNAME.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (WriterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
```

This is not the way you do in fragment class.In fragment there is a View(inflator.inflate) which inflates a layout n by that view you can access all the id's. So you should try something like this:

```
ImagView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store fragment view in class variable.

```
private View myFragmentView;
```

In oncreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_addressinfo_layout, container, false);

    return myFragmentView;
}
```

In your function

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is wrong, you always get the null object reference error as in case of fragment, view binding happens in onCreateView()

you need to do it this way:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // here replace fragment_layout with your xml layout that you have created
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
         ImageView ivQrCode =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.qrCode);

         try {
            Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
            ivQrCode.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return v;
    }
}
```